# Hibernate One to One Association

Tags: hibernate

One to one association in Hibernate can be established by one of these ways.

1. The properties of both classes are maintained in the **same table**.
2. The entities can be maintained in **distinct tables with identical primary keys**.
3. The entities can be maintained in **distinct tables with a key maintained from one of the entities into the other**
   (foreign key relationship between the two tables)

I want to know:

- Does it only depends on database schema?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of these approaches?
  especially I want to know below two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes that are mapped into the same table (**components**) are easy to maintain. You never need to clean up records when data is not used anymore. There are never cascading problems. It is also faster than joined tables. But you can't query for the component, because it is not identified.

You could also use a **join** to map the component (or any other number of properties) to another tables. There might be technical reasons to do so, and there is no difference from point of view of the application. Joins are also implemented by hibernate using identical primary keys.

When using a **one-to-one** relation, you link independent entities. Both can be queried. One of them doesn't have its own identity generator, it takes the id from the other, which makes it dependent on the other. I always had problems when mapping one-to-one relations, because they are hard to understand and actually quite rare.

Alternatively you can map the entities by just using a normal foreign key (**many-to-one**). This is usually easier to understand and maintain. The disadvantage is another foreign key in the database, which could be avoided by using a one-to-one.